# How to understand the following statement: "Assigning a value to a symbolic constant in an executable statement is a syntax error"

Tags: c#, c

I recently encountered the following statement that I was having trouble understanding:

> Assigning a value to a symbolic constant in an executable statement is a syntax error. A symbolic constant is not a variable. No space is reserved for it by the compiler as with variables that hold values at execution time.

Can someone give me an example (either C or C#) of what this is describing to make it more clear what this means?

Comment: If this is the error you are getting please provide more context such as sample code etc. Without that it is almost impossible to help diagnose the issue.

Comment: Sounds like homework to me...

Comment: i found after searching that  symbolic constant  means #define , so it means like #define SIZE 10  ,syntax error will appear if in code you set value to SIZE

Comment: "Check engine light is on can anyone give example about this? A malfunction indicator lamp (MIL), also known as a check engine light, is a tell-tale to indicate malfunction of a computerized engine-management system. It is found on the instrument panel of most automobiles." <- this is what your question would be if it was about cars instead of programming. Is it a good question?

Comment: sorry it is my mistake @immibis i should explain more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking what I think you're asking, here's an example in C#:

```
const int numPeople = 10;
numPeople = 20 + 15;
```

The whole idea of a symbolic constant is just that - it's a constant. If you *could* assign a value to a symbolic constant, it wouldn't be a constant, it would be a variable (which is why the above code won't compile).

In this case, `numPeople` is a symbol representing the constant `10`. It's a named constant in effect. By way of contrast, `20` and `15` are literal constants.

In C and C#, symbolic constants and literal constants should have the same effect in code - it's literally just a substitution. Effectively, `numPeople` does not exist at runtime, it's just a compile-time construct. So the last line of the above code is semantically equivalent to:

```
10 = 20 + 15;
```

which clearly makes no sense.

I wouldn't exactly call this a "common" programming error, by the way, but I guess it does happen.